# How can I reduce a collection to one node when using arrays

Tags: edit-mode

I have a model of a dock which includes the dock, building, bench, bike rack etc and also a row of tires along the edge of the dock made from a single tire and then applying an array modifier so that there are multiple tires along the edge of the dock. When I attempt to reduce the collection to a single node (select All, Ctrl J) the array disappear and I am left with a single tire. What do I need to do to overcome this?

Comment: this should not happen and i am pretty sure you making something more....Can u provide your blend file? this only happens if you did not apply your array modifier...

Comment: maybe there is another array modifier you did not apply?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Firstly I cannot remember how to attach a file. Secondly and most importantly I don't think I have ever 'applied' an array modifier. What I did was to import a model of a tire, select it, then select 'add modifier', then select array and then enter relevant values in the 'count' (fixed count), enter a constant offset value for X and that is all. Is there something else I need to do to apply it?

Comment: because you wrote "applying an array modifier" i thought you had done what i wrote in my answer. But it looks like you just added an array modifier.

Comment: When you Ctrl-J join meshes in a single object, they all acquire the modifiers of the active    (title) object. BTW, a quick way to apply all modifiers to an object is to _Convert_ it to its own type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply a modifier you have to press this little icon [image]

and then choose apply. If you then tap CTRL J to join it should work.

[image]

You can provide your blend file by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and then follow instructions.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I missed this step when I first learned about arrays from a video tutorial. I just tried what you advised above and yes that works.Thanks also for instructions on how to provide a blend file. Would you advise to also reduce a collection to a single node to help prevent unauthorised use of models you may choose to release as freeware?

Comment: I have no experience with releasing as freeware but yes, it would it make more difficult to „reuse“ your model by others. But not impossible. But just as an example: if the meshes are separated, it‘s just a few clicks to separate them as objects again…if they are overlapping - then it is more complicated. Honestly I have no idea how to prevent unauthorized use.